# What the equivalent code in flutter dio compare to android retrofit @body?

Tags: flutter, dio

Now I try to transform my Andorid project to flutter. but I stucked on an api call.

here is my android code in Kotlin:

```
/**
* sendSms
*
* @return 
*/
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@POST("uaa/sms/send/code")
fun sendSms(@Body params: Map<String, String?>): Observable<ApiResult<String>>
```

Now I want to implement this api call in flutter use dio, but I still got wrong, my flutter code

is :

```
class Req {
  static Req _instance;
  
  static const int connectTimeOut = 5 * 1000;

  static const int receiveTimeOut = 7 * 1000;

  static Req getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = Req._internal();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  Dio _client;

  Req._internal() {
    if (_client == null) {
      BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions();
      options.connectTimeout = connectTimeOut;
      options.receiveTimeout = receiveTimeOut;
      _client = new Dio(BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: 'https://gw.ec.iunicorn.com/',
      ));

      // 添加缓存插件
      _client.interceptors.add(Global.netCache);

      //添加token
      _client.interceptors.add(Global.tokenInterceptor);

      _client.interceptors.add(Global.logInterceptor);

      
      // dio.options.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = Global.profile.token;
      _client.options.headers['source'] = 'ANDROID';

      
      if (!Global.isRelease) {
        (_client.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
            (client) {
          // client.findProxy = (uri) {
          //   return "PROXY 10.1.10.250:8888";
          // };
         
          client.badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
        };
      }
    }
  }

  //post请求
  void post(
      String url,
      OnData callBack, {
        Map<String, String> params,
        Options options,
        FormData formData,
        OnError errorCallBack,
        CancelToken token,
      }) async {
    this._request(
      url,
      callBack,
      method: RequestType.POST,
      options: options,
      formData: formData,
      params: params,
      errorCallBack: errorCallBack,
      token: token,
    );
  }

  void _request(
      String url,
      OnData callBack, {
        RequestType method,
        Map<String, String> params,
        Options options,
        FormData formData,
        OnError errorCallBack,
        ProgressCallback progressCallBack,
        CancelToken token,
      }) async {
    final id = _id++;
    int statusCode;
    try {
      Response response;
      if (method == RequestType.GET) {

        if (mapNoEmpty(params)) {
          response = await _client.get(url,
              queryParameters: params, cancelToken: token);
        } else {
          response = await _client.get(url, cancelToken: token);
        }
      } else {
        if (mapNoEmpty(params) || formData != null) {
          response = await _client.post(
            url,
            data: formData ?? params,
            onSendProgress: progressCallBack,
            cancelToken: token,
          );
        } else {
          response = await _client.post(url, cancelToken: token);
        }
      }

      statusCode = response.statusCode;

      if (response != null) {
        if (response.data is List) {
          Map data = response.data[0];
          callBack(data);
        } else {
          Map data = response.data;
          callBack(data);
        }
        print('HTTP_REQUEST_URL::[$id]::$url');
        print('HTTP_REQUEST_BODY::[$id]::${params ?? ' no'}');
        print('HTTP_RESPONSE_BODY::[$id]::${response.data}');
      }


      if (statusCode < 0) {
        _handError(errorCallBack, statusCode);
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _handError(errorCallBack, statusCode);
    }
  }

  ///处理异常
  static void _handError(OnError errorCallback, int statusCode) {
    String errorMsg = 'Network request error';
    if (errorCallback != null) {
      errorCallback(errorMsg, statusCode);
    }
    print("HTTP_RESPONSE_ERROR::$errorMsg code:$statusCode");
  }
}

void sendSms(BuildContext context, Callback callback) async {
  Req.getInstance().post(
      ApiPath.SEND_SMS,
      (t) {
        SmsResponse r = SmsResponse.fromJson(t);
        print(r);
        if (callback != null) {
          callback();
        }
      },
      formData: FormData.fromMap({
        'phoneNumber':'182********'
      }),
      options: RequestOptions(
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          }),
      errorCallBack: (msg, code) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: AppLocalizations.of(context).send_sms_fail,
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1);
      });
}
```

Now I want to know is the data in dio is equivalent to the @Body in java retrofit, if not, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in plain `Dio` leads to a lot of boilerplate. There is also an equivalent retrofit package for Flutter inspired by the same package for Android. https://pub.dev/packages?q=retrofit

From there it's almost the same, you just add () after @Body. Here is an example

```
@POST('/auth/change-password')
Future<bool> changePassword({
  @required @Body() Map<String, dynamic> params,
  @required @Header('auth-token') String token,
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I had get the right response by using dart retrofit.